# How much to charge for adding features to website

Tags: freelance-websites, pay-rate

I got a freelance project to add few features to an existing website. This is my first independent project and I'm confused about how much to charge. There are four features to add. 
1. Allow the site admin to add tutor profiles to the site and the users should be able to filter those profiles and request for that particular tutor. 
2. Allow the admin to post jobs on the site and the users will filter the jobs and apply for the jobs directly from the site. 
3. A custom calendar for users to plan their studies and also collaborate and share with other users' time table. 
4. Let users post questions for us or for other users to be answered. More of a forum.

I need to give them a quote and need an overall idea of how much to charge on this.

Comment: **No one** else can set your prices for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use your best guess as to how long you think the project will take, including any revisions, and multiply it by your desired hourly rate. You may also want to add in some "overhead" to cover the time you spent bidding on the project and the possibility of more back-and-forth with the client than you expected.

Or you can bill out the actual time you spend on the project.